# Call controller function from angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I call angular function inside directive which is defined in controller?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

app.directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            myObj: '=hello'
        },
        template: '<button  class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="dirFunction()">Click</button>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.dirFunction = function () {
                scope.count++;
                console.log('I am dirFunction');
            };
            var countChange = function (someVar) {
               console.log('I am countChange');
              // scope.changeCount(someVar); // call  changeCount() defined in controller
            };

           // scope.$watch('myObj', hello);
            scope.$watch('count', countChange);
        }
    }
});


function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Can I do it?';
    $scope.myObj = {data:'I need this data object',count:1};

    $scope.changeCount = function(someVar) {
        console.log("I am changeCount from controller,I have someVar in hand");
    }

}
```

I need to call the commented `scope.changeCount(someVar);` in directive.

See HTML,

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="row">
          {{message}}
          <div hello="myObj"></div>  
        </div><!--/row-->
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8MG/111/)**

Comment: you can pass the controller to your linking function and use it
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `&` while invoking a controller function on the parent scope from inside a directive using an isolate scope:

### HTML

```
<div hello="myObj" change-count="changeCount(someVar)"></div>
```

### Directive

```
app.directive('hello', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            myObj: '=hello',
            changeCount:"&changeCount"
        },
        template: '<button class="..." ng-click="dirFunction()">Click</button>',
        link: function (scope) {
            scope.dirFunction = function () {
                scope.myObj.count++;
                console.log('I am dirFunction '+scope.myObj.count);
            };
            var countChange = function (someVar) {
                console.log('I am countChange '+someVar);
                scope.changeCount({'someVar':someVar});
            };             
            scope.$watch('myObj.count', function(newValue){
                countChange(newValue)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PwRqX/)**</kbd>

Comment: But one problem, how can I access variable send from directive in controller?

Comment: @iDevoc I have updated my answer and attached the updated fiddle as well.

Comment: @2614013 Thanks, based on this, I need to fix one problem which passes two arguments.Can you please help me to do this http://jsfiddle.net/Rd8MG/112/ . I am trying to call ``scope.changePage(newPage, last_page);`` on line 64, it gives me error.